# Python [Tkinter] Rock Paper Scissors GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

I am currently working on a Python [Tkinter] Rock Paper Scissors GUI application. So far I've been able to construct the interface and even allow the user to make their selection. The only problem is I cannot figure out how to print out the computer's decision. I want to be able to update a label or upload an image depending on what the computer picked. For example, The user clicks on rock, and I want to be able to print to the window a image of a rock, OR the word rock, and have it update the next time the user picks a new option such as scissors or paper and have it reset. So in simplistic words, I want to be able to create an updating image or / text (Label) every time a user clicks a button.
P.S the only reason im using pygame is to allow my application to run with music. Also I've supplied screenshots below of the application.

***Code:***

```
#Written by : Pamal Mangat.
#Written on : Monday, July 27th, 2015.
#Rock Paper Scissors : Version 1.2 (Tkinter [GUI] addition)

from tkinter import *
from sys import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import pygame as py
import os
from random import randrange

py.init()

#Function runs the actual game. 
def runGame(startWindow):

#Close [startWindow] before advancing:
startWindow.destroy()
startWindow.quit()

master = Tk()
master.title('Lets Play!')

#Function carries on the remainder of the game.
def carryGame(button_id):

    result = StringVar()
    printResult = Label(master, textvariable = result, font='Bizon 32 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
    printResult.place(x=150, y=300)

    #Computer's move:
    random_Num = randrange(1,4)

    if random_Num == 1:
       computer_Move = 'Rock'

    elif random_Num == 2:
        computer_Move = 'Paper'

    else:
        computer_Move = 'Scissors'

    if button_id == 1:
        player_Move = 'Rock'

    elif button_id == 2:
        player_Move = 'Paper'

    else:
        player_Move = 'Scissors'

#Rock button
rock_Button = Button(master, width=15, height=7, command=lambda:carryGame(1))
rock_photo=PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Images\rock.png')
rock_Button.config(image=rock_photo,width="120",height="120")
rock_Button.place(x=17, y=70)

#Paper button
paper_Button = Button(master, width=15, height=7, command=lambda:carryGame(2))
paper_photo=PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Images\paper.png')
paper_Button.config(image=paper_photo,width="120",height="120")
paper_Button.place(x=167, y=70)

#Scissors button
scissors_Button = Button(master, width=15, height=7, command=lambda:carryGame(3))
scissors_photo=PhotoImage(file=r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Images\scissors.png')
scissors_Button.config(image=scissors_photo,width="120",height="120")
scissors_Button.place(x=317, y=70)

label_1 = Label(master, text='Please make your selection-', font='Bizon 20 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
label_1.pack(side=TOP)

label_2 = Label(master, text='The computer picked:', font='Helvetica 22 bold', bg='PeachPuff2')
label_2.place(x=70, y=240)

#Locks window size
master.maxsize(450, 400)
master.minsize(450, 400)

#Sets window background to PeachPuff2
master.config(background='PeachPuff2')

master.mainloop()

def startScreen():

    #Plays music for the application
    def playMusic(fileName):
        py.mixer.music.load(fileName)
        py.mixer.music.play()

    #Start Window
    startWindow = Tk()
    startWindow.title('[Rock] [Paper] [Scissors]')

    #Imports image as title
    load = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Images\title.png')
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
    img = Label(startWindow, image=render, bd=0)
    img.image = render
    img.place(x=-100, y=-65)

    clickToPlay = Button(startWindow, text='Play!', width=8, font='Bizon 20 bold', bg='Black', fg='Yellow', relief=RIDGE, bd=0, command=lambda:runGame(startWindow))
    clickToPlay.place(x=75, y=125)

    #Credit
    authorName = Label(startWindow, text='Written by : Pamal Mangat', font='Times 6 bold', bg='Black', fg='Yellow')
    authorName.place(x=2, y=230)

    versionNum = Label(startWindow, text='[V 1.2]', font='Times 6 bold', bg='Black', fg='Red')
    versionNum.place(x=268, y=230)

    #Start Screen Music
    playMusic(r'C:\Users\Pamal\Desktop\Documents\Python Folder\Python Projects\Rock, Paper, Scissors\V 1.2\Audio\title_Song.mp3')

    #Locks window size
    startWindow.maxsize(300, 250)
    startWindow.minsize(300, 250)

    #Sets window background to black
    startWindow.config(background='Black')

    startWindow.mainloop()

startScreen()
```

***Screenshots:***

An image of the starting screen:

[image]

An image of the window that opens up after clicking play on the starting screen: 
[image]

The blue circled area is where i want the computer's decision to be displayed.

Comment: To do that, you need to create some kind of widget or object there (like a `Label` or something), then simply reconfigure its image with `config()`.

Comment: Is there some function that is *guaranteed* to run just prior to needing to display the computer's response? (Hint: in carryGame() you already compute the computer's move, you just don't display it.)

Comment: I know how to aqquire the computer's move and i know how to determine it's move, but the only problem i have is updating it everytime, i've figured how to print it once but updating is my concern

Comment: Also how would i make a counter (label) that determines the number of wins the user and computer have against each other?

Answer (score 0):

After the player has chosen, simply create a label located under label_2, and make it say the variable computer_move. Remember to use the right capitals for your variable, i didnt but i hope you get the point.

Comment: you don't want to create a label each time the player chooses. You want to create the label once and then update it.